# Node.js with Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, node.js, amazon-web-services, laravel-4, ratchet

I currently working on **php** project - Laravel 4.2 framework. I need to use **node.js**. Need to real time update count of users  that registered, on dashbord.

I tried with [Ratchet](http://www.socketo.me/docs/hello-world) , but I'm not clear following file path that we must edit.

- /src/MyApp/Chat.php
- /bin/chat-server.php

Does someone have experience working with node.js on Laravel?
Please help me.

Comment: You could use publish/subscribe pattern with Redis on both Laravel and Node. When a new user is created (on Laravel) you could publish the user count to a Redis topic e.g. "users/count" through Laravel's Redis client. Now on Node you can use a Redis client that subscribe to "users/count" topic, so when something is published you could emit data received from that topic to the websockets you want.

Comment: @SergioGuillenMantilla Thanks , I'll try with Laravel's Redis client.

Comment: First read something about publish/subscribe, also I found this post, maybe it will be useful for you http://www.volkomenjuist.nl/blog/2013/10/20/laravel-4-and-nodejsredis-pubsub-realtime-notifications/

Comment: @SergioGuillenMantilla Thanks, I'm following it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried many ways to integrate Nodejs with my application, but finally I used **Faye**. I put my code on following link.

[Node js Faye Client not working properly with HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502251/node-js-faye-client-not-working-properly-with-https?noredirect=1#comment49080482_30502251)

This work fine. If you have another solutions, You are welcome